# array to NSOrderedSet change size of list to 1

Tags: arrays, swift, core-data, nsorderedset

I have a array of 2 element, when i try to convert it to NSOrderedSet it give me a size of only one element

```
      LOG("\(listTwoElement.count)")
```

This line give me 2

```
   LOG("\(NSOrderedSet.init(array: listTwoElement).count)")
```

this line give me only 1 element

Why conversion to NSOrderedSet change size of array ?

thanks for your help

Comment: Both values in the array must be the same.

Comment: What is `listTwoElement`? What is `listjj`? @rmaddy Actually *Both values in the array must **not** be the same*

Comment: @vadian I read the question too quickly. I thought the ordered set was being created from the same array being printed. But if you create an ordered set from an array and the array contains two objects that compare as equal, then the set will only have one object.

Comment: @vadian sorry two are listTwoElement there is no listjj i just wrong on past code. I corrected that

Comment: thank you for your responses guys, the element of array are the same this was my problem, i kept OrderedSet now i put there only different elements and now its work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A **Set** is an unordered list of unique elements.  If you try to put the same element in a set twice you will only get one

An **Array** is an order list of elements that needn't be unique.  You can have the same element may times in array.

A **OrderedSet** is a combination of both (but a subclass of neither).  The items are ordered, like an array, but each element needs to be unique.

Unique element does not (just) mean that they are stored in different locations in memory, but that they are not "equal" in some fundamental sense.  Equality can be defined differently for every class.  Classes that want to define it, implement the `isEqual:` and `hash` method of the `NSObjectProtocol`. (Hashes of equal objects must be equal, hashes of unequal object do not need to be different).

Without knowing more about the element you are dealing with it is hard to say why they are being evaluated as equal when you don't expect them to be.  I would start will looking at the class's implementation of the `isEqual` and `hash`.

Comment: Thank you for your response, they are the same this was my problem, i kept OrderedSet know i put there only different elements and now its work